# confirmation dialog box in rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

I have the following code in my rjs template which displays a confirm box:

```
page << "r = confirm('Would you like to link this newly created author to the book?')"
```

I tried

```
`page << "if r == true {"`   
 #do action a
`page << "} else {"`  
 #do action b
`page << "}"`
```

The code above is incorrect.

My question is how do I get the value of the selection (true or false) made in the confirm box?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this syntax :

```
page << "var r = confirm('Would you like to link this newly created author to the book?');"

page << "if (r == true) {" 
  #do action a
page << "} else {"
  #do action b
page << "}"
```

I tried and it seems to work.